# TeamCity w/ git - run build after another build, but only a specific branch

Tags: git, github, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have two branches in git: master and "deploy" (not the real name but good for this example.  When I want to deploy things to the test server, I merge those changes into deploy branch and I want TC to automatically deploy them.  So I have a Build and a Deploy config set up in TeamCity.  Build is set up to build all branches, so commits in both branches trigger builds.  I want to set up the Deploy config to run only after a successful Build, and only if that Build was against the deploy branch.  I see that I can set up a Snapshot Dependency, which seems like what I want, but I can't figure out how to limit it to only that branch.  I want to guarantee that the Deploy build runs against the same source as the Build for the deploy branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your builds to the `deploy` branch via the the VCS Root configuration screen.

1. Clear the *Default branch* field.
2. Add the `refs/heads/deploy` branch to the *Branch specification* field.

[image: TeamCity branch specification]

In order to integrate this change with a build template, you can parameterize the *Branch specification* as `%git.branch.specification%`.

- For **branch** builds, the value is set to `refs/heads/*`
- For **deploy** builds, the value is set to `refs/heads/deploy`

Comment: The dependent deploy build has no VCS root.  I want it to use the same checkout dir as the build which does the actual source building.

Comment: If you tie everything to a build template, you can have your cake and eat it too. The 'deploy' configuration can just build and deploy the branch on its own.

Comment: I get what you're saying. Trying to find a way where I don't do the build twice.  But yeah this would probably work.

Comment: Yeah, that might be possible with a little tinkering. You might be able to tell the 'branch' config to exclude the 'deploy' branch by specifying `-:refs/heads/deploy`. Our team is still figuring out how to tweak this sort of thing.

Comment: Any joy with this kind of thing? I have a similar issue I'd like to resolve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333809/teamcity-build-dependencies-and-choosing-the-correct-branch