# TeamCity build dependencies and choosing the correct branch

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a single project with three build configurations:

1. Integration
2. Deploy Dev
3. Deploy Release

Build configs 2 and 3 are dependent on 1 via a snapshot.

There are 3 VCS roots:

1. Git - All (used with build config 1)
2. Git - Develop (used with build config 2)
3. Git - Master (used with build config 3)

The default branch and branch specs are as follows:

**Git - All**

default branch:

> develop

branch spec:

> +:refs/heads/(develop)
>   +:refs/heads/(master)
>   +:refs/heads/(feature/*)
>
>   +:refs/heads/(hotfix/*)
>   +:refs/heads/(release)
>   +:refs/heads/(support/*)

**Git - Develop**

default branch:

> develop

branch spec:

> +:refs/heads/(develop)

**Git - Master**

default branch:

> master

branch spec:

> +:refs/heads/(master)

Here is the problem...

When I run a build for the third build config, I want the dependency to check for integration builds on the master branch. It is not doing and will always use the default branch of the integration build config (currently develop).

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

- Have a single integration build config
- Have a separate build config that is dependent on only develop branch updates
- Have a separate build config that is dependent on only master branch updates

The way I have done it in the past involved using multiple CVS end points on a single build config, which also seems wrong and I wanted to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue now... :/

Comment: Me too - same exact setup as you have. Any luck?

Comment: I'm afraid not, it's a while back so I cannot recall exactly but I think I left it at reporting incorrect pending changes. Sorry can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a variable for branch spec and VCS trigger. That allows you to reuse the VCS root, while still giving you the flexibility to choose the values in each build configuration.

Comment: Thanks, so would this be a variable in the default branch and branch spec fields? It is caused because TeamCity uses <default> instead of the actual name of the branch across build configs. I changed it to a single VCS route shortly after I posted the question but now get false pending change reports for the different branches. If you could elaborate on your answer that would be great.

Comment: Could you please clarify the phrase "It is caused because TeamCity uses ...". What is caused by that?

Comment: The reason it picks the wrong dependency build. As the Deploy Release build config is running from the "<default>" branch of its VCS route, it looks for a dependency in the Integration build config that matches. As it's used "<default>" instead of the actual logical branch name it picks the Integration build that equates to the develop branch, which is wrong, which is causing me my issue.